# WordPress AJAX PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

If I take Wordpresses AJAX/PHP example how would I call $whatever in another function? If I do get a result outside of the initial function (below) it is always 0.

```html
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
 global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

 $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

 $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever; //

 die();
}
```

[Wordpress AJAX plugin code example page](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

I suspect it is very simple but when you get in a certain mindset you cannot look beyond the blinders.

Comment: What you have tried for that. provide your code here

Comment: what kind of function do you need to call $whatever in? If your goal is to use it in another function during that ajax request, you need to call that function with $whatever as a parameter in your my_action_callback function.